# Capture billing address changes Apple Pay JS

Tags: applepay, applepayjs

I am looking for a way to capture the billing address changes using Apple Pay JS. I am currently using the [`onpaymentmethodselected`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession/1778013-onpaymentmethodselected) to capture this which is correctly firing when selecting a new card.

However when selecting just a new billing address (e.g. Address #2 - which is different from the card's default address) using the options under the "Billing Address" heading, the payment card is switched to use that address however the event is not being sent.

Is there another way to intercept the selection of this activity from a user or a way to disable this additional interface?

[image: apple pay desktop payment sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue on older versions of macOS Big Sur (11.7.2) as this UI is no longer available on more up-to-date versions like macOS Ventura 13.4.1.

We got around this by comparing the country/state codes provided by the [onpaymentauthorized](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession/1778020-onpaymentauthorized) against the value we received from [onpaymentmethodselected](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession/1778013-onpaymentmethodselected).